# Why does Simple Backpropagation beat Nesterov and RMSProp

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, backpropagation

I was trying to implement a Neural Net on my own and it worked out pretty well. However , when I tried out different algorithms for optimization the results got a bit confusing for me. Maybe there is something wrong with my Implementation?

I expected Nesterov and RMSProp to give out better results than the simple backPropagation and Momentum Method. But NoMomentum and Momentum Method beat RMSProp and Nesterov every time. I updates the weights after each training instance and did 400 epochs of the Pima Indian Diabetes Dataset.

[image: First Run]

[image: Second Run]

Here is the Jupyter Notebook for the test runs:-[Full Code](https://github.com/RiteshBM/FeedForwardNeuralNet1)

There are three layers in the net, sigmoid is used as activation for the hidden layer and softmax is used in output layer for output predictions.

Before I expose you to the sea of unknown variables , I would like to explain their use:-

Wij:- Set of weights between Input and Hidden.

Wjk:-Set of weights between Hidden and Output.

dEdOLo:- Derivative of Error w.r.t OutputLayerOuput

dOLoOLi:- Derivative of OutputLayerOutput w.r.t OutputLayerInput

dWij:- Set of derivatives of Error w.r.t weights.

dWjk:- Set of derivatives of Error w.r.t weights.

lWij:- Running Average for Wij.

lWjk:-Running Average for Wjk.

ILi:-Input Layer input

ILo:-Input Layer output

HLi:-Hidden Layer input

HLo:-Hidden Layer output

OLi:-Output Layer input

OLo:-Output Layer input

alpha:- Learning Rate.

beta:-Decay Constant.

I tried out:-

Momentum Method

```
def bprop_momentum(self,ILi,Outpute,alpha,beta):
    self.dEdOLo=self.SEd(self.OLo,Outpute)
    self.dOLoOLi=self.OLo*(1-self.OLo)  
    self.dWjk=np.dot(self.HLo.T,(self.dEdOLo*self.dOLoOLi))
    self.dWij=np.dot(self.ILo.T,np.dot(self.Wjk,(self.OLo*(1-self.OLo)*self.dEdOLo).T).T*self.HLo*(1-self.HLo))
    self.lWij=beta*self.lWij+(1-beta)*self.dWij
    self.lWjk=beta*self.lWjk+(1-beta)*self.dWjk
    self.Wij-=(self.lWij*alpha)
    self.Wjk-=(self.lWjk*alpha)
```

Nesterov Method:-

```
def bprop_nesterov(self,ILi,Outpute,alpha,beta):
    self.dEdOLo=self.SEd(self.OLo,Outpute)
    self.dOLoOLi=self.OLo*(1-self.OLo)  
    self.dWjk=np.dot(self.HLo.T,(self.dEdOLo*self.dOLoOLi))
    self.dWij=np.dot(self.ILo.T,np.dot(self.Wjk-alpha*self.lWjk,(self.OLo*(1-self.OLo)*self.dEdOLo).T).T*self.HLo*(1-self.HLo))
    self.lWij=beta*self.lWij+(1-beta)*self.dWij
    self.lWjk=beta*self.lWjk+(1-beta)*self.dWjk
    self.Wij-=(self.lWij*alpha)
    self.Wjk-=(self.lWjk*alpha)
```

RMSProp Method:-

```
def bprop_rmsprop(self,ILi,Outpute,alpha,beta):
    self.dEdOLo=self.SEd(self.OLo,Outpute)
    self.dOLoOLi=self.OLo*(1-self.OLo)  
    self.dWjk=np.dot(self.HLo.T,(self.dEdOLo*self.dOLoOLi))
    self.dWij=np.dot(self.ILo.T,np.dot(self.Wjk,(self.OLo*(1-self.OLo)*self.dEdOLo).T).T*self.HLo*(1-self.HLo))
    self.lWij=beta*self.lWij+(1-beta)*(self.dWij*self.dWij)
    self.lWjk=beta*self.lWjk+(1-beta)*(self.dWjk*self.dWjk)
    self.Wij-=((self.dWij/(self.lWij**0.5 +0.000001))*alpha)
    self.Wjk-=((self.dWjk/(self.lWjk**0.5 +0.000001))*alpha)
```

Comment: Why would one optimizer need to be better than another one? There is no theoretical justification for this. See [the NFL theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) and also [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08292).

Comment: thanks for the help @cheersmate ,The theorem and the paper helped a lot. I guess I was wrong to assume that some models outperform others , it seems like momentum and nesterov only guarantee to achieve higher accuracy quicker and not an overall improvement over simple backpropagation.

Comment: In practice, you just try out and use the algorithm which works best. The changes may be larger or smaller, depending on the exact problem.